# A Simple way of Loading a BLDC Motor?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I am looking for loading a [15W BLDC motor](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Hurst%20DMB0224C10002%20BLDC%20Motor%20DataSheet.pdf) with another BLDC machine, sort of like a master slave configuration. I'm not exactly sure how the slave BLDC machine windings should be connected. One idea was to [short the windings](https://www.circuitsathome.com/measurements/dummy-load-for-brushless-motor-controller) together. Another is to connect resistors to the slave machine's terminals, operated as a generator, as loads. But in what configuration, star or delta? Can potentiometers be used? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[OLD TEXT]
<s>I have a [15W Hurst brushless dc motor](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Hurst%20DMB0224C10002%20BLDC%20Motor%20DataSheet.pdf), whose rated torque is 0.07Nm, rated speed 2054 rpm (~215 rad/sec). I am looking for a simple method of exerting 0.07N.m load at rated speed, without having to purchase a magnetic brake (they're expensive). One idea I had was to attach an adjustable coupling of a specific weight to the shaft (radius ~ 0.004m). The coupling, having a certain mass and inertia, will exert a specific amount of load on the shaft at a certain angular speed (supposedly). Since the coupling is a hollow cylinder, the inertia can be given by</s>

<s>Inertia = mass \times radius^2 [kg.m^2]</s>

<s>Then the torque can be calculated as</s>

<s>Torque = speed \times mass \times radius^2 [N.m]</s>

*Edit: This formula for calculating torque is wrong as pointed out in comments*

<s>However, I suspect that its not that simple. The formula can be altogether wrong. With this formulas, for a coupling inner radius of 0.004 m, speed of 2100 rpm, I get around 20 kg of mass for the coupling, which is huge!!!</s>

<s>Can you please provide your inputs on this matter (*Edit: How to best load the motor without a magnetic brake*)?</s>

Comment: do you have 2 of these machines? or access to another?

Comment: You can't apply a constant torque to a rotating shaft just connecting a sort of fly-wheel: if the angular velocity is constant then torque is zero. That's probably why people use magnetic brakes, and definitely why your calculations leads to wrong results. Even the measurements units are wrong. And on top of all this question has nothing to do with electronic design, you're better off to the engineering stack. Just fix your physics or be prepared to be chewed up.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about electronic design.

Comment: @JonRB actually I do have an same rating BLDC, with slightly different internal parameters.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Actually I converted all units to SI before performing calculations. A certain mass at a fixed speed should yield a constant torque. I am well aware that varying the speed will vary the torque. This problem is related to doing load test of a BLDC motor drive. It is crucial in testing your controller speed regulation performance.

Comment: let me say it again: your measurement units are **wrong**: you calculate torque as speed times mass times radius squared, that is m/s * kg * m^2 that is N*m*s and tha is not a torque. Torque is the inertia times angular acceleration, with constans speed angular acceleration is zero, thus you have no torque

Comment: @VladimirCravero You are correct! I take back my wrong statement. The quantity I am calculating is not torque.

Comment: That's how you can make a dummy load for brushless motor -> https://www.circuitsathome.com/measurements/dummy-load-for-brushless-motor-controller  If you want variable load add resistors or current sinks where I shorted the windings.